# How to generate entropy for gpg? CentOS 7 VM

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, gnupg, entropy

I am using CentOS 7 in a VM (Parallels).  My gpg key generation needs more entropy to generate the keys.  I get the following message:

```
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
```

What can I do to generate random bytes for this process?

I have tried some tricks for generating entropy but it seems i need more random bits.

Somethings that have worked for others but not me:

```
1# ls -R /
2# sudo md5sum /dev/sda &
```

Command #1 generates about 15 bits every 2 seconds.
Command #2 generate minimal amount of entropy.

Comment: see this at serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/214605/gpg-not-enough-entropy

Comment: Thanks for the response @MarkusLaire. I looked at the post. It requires installing an additional package. I repeated command #1 in a loop and it was able to generate enough entropy for my 4096 bit key. Ex. # for i in {1..100} ; do ls -R / ; done.  If additional entropy is required, repeat the loop.  Although it will take a little longer to generate enough entropy, it can be done in offline mode. Also, I don't understand how the package generates the random bits.  For someone paranoid, this is the preferred method.

Comment: It takes entropy from `/dev/urandom` which does not block instead of `/dev/random` which can block. Google about them to learn more, these are standard devices in linux.